# How can I get all the abbreviations of vim's options?

Tags: vim, abbreviation

Such as I can use

```
:set nu
```

as

```
:set number
```

Where can I get the whole list of this kind of mapping (number -> nu)?

Or can I define new abbreviations?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get short option name from long option name in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3829425).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### List of options in Vim 8.0

Grepping lines matching `^\s*\*'\w\+'\*` in `options.txt` from vim help, and removing words not surrounded with quotes provides the following list.

It has to be tweaked a bit because for `conceallevel` the help line is not like the others, for some options they span on two lines, *etc* so this list cannot, alas, be generated automatically.

You can reach the help section for any option with `:help 'optionname'`.

Note for all options allowing the prefix `no` (the boolean ones), the prefix `inv` is also allowed.

What follows is therefore a list of all authorized spellings of options in vim. Options on the same line are shortcut or negative form or shortcut of negative form of the first form.

Sorry, table misses formatting because of the answer length limit.

```
    long       | short   | bool | variants
    form       | form    |      | (negation and inversion)
---------------|---------|------|
aleph          | al      |      |
allowrevins    | ari     |  X   | noallowrevins    noari     invallowrevins    invari
altkeymap      | akm     |  X   | noaltkeymap      noakm     invaltkeymap      invakm
ambiwidth      | ambw    |      |
antialias      | anti    |  X   | noantialias      noanti    invantialias      invanti
arabic         | arab    |  X   | noarabic         noarab    invarabic         invarab
arabicshape    | arshape |  X   | noarabicshape    noarshape invarabicshape    invarshape
autochdir      | acd     |  X   | noautochdir      noacd     invautochdir      invacd
autoindent     | ai      |  X   | noautoindent     noai      invautoindent     invai
autoread       | ar      |  X   | noautoread       noar      invautoread       invar
autowrite      | aw      |  X   | noautowrite      noaw      invautowrite      invaw
autowriteall   | awa     |  X   | noautowriteall   noawa     invautowriteall   invawa
background     | bg      |      |
backspace      | bs      |      |
backup         | bk      |  X   | nobackup         nobk      invbackup         invbk
backupcopy     | bkc     |      |
backupdir      | bdir    |      |
backupext      | bex     |      |
backupskip     | bsk     |      |
balloondelay   | bdlay   |      |
ballooneval    | beval   |  X   | noballooneval    nobeval   invballooneval    invbeval
balloonexpr    | bexpr   |      |
belloff        | bo      |      |
binary         | bin     |  X   | nobinary         nobin     invbinary         invbin
bioskey        | biosk   |  X   | nobioskey        nobiosk   invbioskey        invbiosk
bomb           |         |  X   | nobomb                     invbomb
breakat        | brk     |      |
breakindent    | bri     |  X   | nobreakindent    nobri     invbreakindent    invbri
breakindentopt | briopt  |      |
browsedir      | bsdir   |      |
bufhidden      | bh      |      |
buflisted      | bl      |  X   | nobuflisted      nobl      invbuflisted      invbl
buftype        | bt      |      |
casemap        | cmp     |      |
cdpath         | cd      |      |
cedit          |         |      |
charconvert    | ccv     |      |
cindent        | cin     |  X   | nocindent        nocin     invcindent        invcin
cinkeys        | cink    |      |
cinoptions     | cino    |      |
cinwords       | cinw    |      |
clipboard      | cb      |      |
cmdheight      | ch      |      |
cmdwinheight   | cwh     |      |
colorcolumn    | cc      |      |
columns        | co      |      |
comments       | com     |      |
commentstring  | cms     |      |
compatible     | cp      |  X   | nocompatible     nocp      invcompatible     invcp
complete       | cpt     |      |
completefunc   | cfu     |      |
completeopt    | cot     |      |
concealcursor  | cocu    |      |
conceallevel   | cole    |      |
confirm        | cf      |  X   | noconfirm        nocf      invconfirm        invcf
conskey        | consk   |  X   | noconskey        noconsk   invconskey        invconsk
copyindent     | ci      |  X   | nocopyindent     noci      invcopyindent     invci
cpoptions      | cpo     |      |
cryptmethod    | cm      |      |
cscopepathcomp | cspc    |      |
cscopeprg      | csprg   |      |
cscopequickfix | csqf    |      |
cscoperelative | csre    |  X   | nocscoperelative nocsre    invcscoperelative invcsre
cscopetag      | cst     |  X   | nocscopetag      nocst     invcscopetag      invcst
cscopetagorder | csto    |      |
cscopeverbose  | csverb  |  X   | nocscopeverbose  nocsverb  invcscopeverbose  invcsverb
cursorbind     | crb     |  X   | nocursorbind     nocrb     invcursorbind     invcrb
cursorcolumn   | cuc     |  X   | nocursorcolumn   nocuc     invcursorcolumn   invcuc
cursorline     | cul     |  X   | nocursorline     nocul     invcursorline     invcul
debug          |         |      |
define         | def     |      |
delcombine     | deco    |  X   | nodelcombine     nodeco    invdelcombine     invdeco
dictionary     | dict    |      |
diff           |         |  X   | nodiff                     invdiff
diffexpr       | dex     |      |
diffopt        | dip     |      |
digraph        | dg      |  X   | nodigraph        nodg      invdigraph        invdg
directory      | dir     |      |
display        | dy      |      |
eadirection    | ead     |      |
edcompatible   | ed      |  X   | noedcompatible   noed      invedcompatible   inved
emoji          | emo     |  X   | noemoji          noemo     invemoji          invemo
encoding       | enc     |      |
endofline      | eol     |  X   | noendofline      noeol     invendofline      inveol
equalalways    | ea      |  X   | noequalalways    noea      invequalalways    invea
equalprg       | ep      |      |
errorbells     | eb      |  X   | noerrorbells     noeb      inverrorbells     inveb
errorfile      | ef      |      |
errorformat    | efm     |      |
esckeys        | ek      |  X   | noesckeys        noek      invesckeys        invek
eventignore    | ei      |      |
expandtab      | et      |  X   | noexpandtab      noet      invexpandtab      invet
exrc           | ex      |  X   | noexrc           noex      invexrc           invex
fe             |         |      |
fileencoding   | fenc    |      |
fileencodings  | fencs   |      |
fileformat     | ff      |      |
fileformats    | ffs     |      |
fileignorecase | fic     |  X   | nofileignorecase nofic     invfileignorecase invfic
filetype       | ft      |      |
fillchars      | fcs     |      |
fixendofline   | fixeol  |  X   | nofixendofline   nofixeol  invfixendofline   invfixeol
fkmap          | fk      |  X   | nofkmap          nofk      invfkmap          invfk
foldclose      | fcl     |      |
foldcolumn     | fdc     |      |
foldenable     | fen     |  X   | nofoldenable     nofen     invfoldenable     invfen
foldexpr       | fde     |      |
foldignore     | fdi     |      |
foldlevel      | fdl     |      |
foldlevelstart | fdls    |      |
foldmarker     | fmr     |      |
foldmethod     | fdm     |      |
foldminlines   | fml     |      |
foldnestmax    | fdn     |      |
foldopen       | fdo     |      |
foldtext       | fdt     |      |
formatexpr     | fex     |      |
formatlistpat  | flp     |      |
formatoptions  | fo      |      |
formatprg      | fp      |      |
fsync          | fs      |  X   | nofsync          nofs      invfsync          invfs
gdefault       | gd      |  X   | nogdefault       nogd      invgdefault       invgd
grepformat     | gfm     |      |
grepprg        | gp      |      |
guicursor      | gcr     |      |
guifont        | gfn     |      |
guifontset     | gfs     |      |
guifontwide    | gfw     |      |
guiheadroom    | ghr     |      |
guioptions     | go      |      |
guipty         |         |  X   | noguipty                   invguipty
guitablabel    | gtl     |      |
guitabtooltip  | gtt     |      |
helpfile       | hf      |      |
helpheight     | hh      |      |
helplang       | hlg     |      |
hidden         | hid     |  X   | nohidden         nohid     invhidden         invhid
highlight      | hl      |      |
history        | hi      |      |
hkmap          | hk      |  X   | nohkmap          nohk      invhkmap          invhk
hkmapp         | hkp     |  X   | nohkmapp         nohkp     invhkmapp         invhkp
hlsearch       | hls     |  X   | nohlsearch       nohls     invhlsearch       invhls
icon           |         |  X   | noicon                     invicon
iconstring     |         |      |
ignorecase     | ic      |  X   | noignorecase     noic      invignorecase     invic
imactivatefunc | imaf    |      |
imactivatekey  | imak    |      |
imcmdline      | imc     |  X   | noimcmdline      noimc     invimcmdline      invimc
imdisable      | imd     |  X   | noimdisable      noimd     invimdisable      invimd
iminsert       | imi     |      |
imsearch       | ims     |      |
imstatusfunc   | imsf    |      |
include        | inc     |      |
includeexpr    | inex    |      |
incsearch      | is      |  X   | noincsearch      nois      invincsearch      invis
indentexpr     | inde    |      |
indentkeys     | indk    |      |
infercase      | inf     |  X   | noinfercase      noinf     invinfercase      invinf
insertmode     | im      |  X   | noinsertmode     noim      invinsertmode     invim
isfname        | isf     |      |
isident        | isi     |      |
iskeyword      | isk     |      |
isprint        | isp     |      |
joinspaces     | js      |  X   | nojoinspaces     nojs      invjoinspaces     invjs
key            |         |      |
keymap         | kmp     |      |
keymodel       | km      |      |
keywordprg     | kp      |      |
langmap        | lmap    |      |
langmenu       | lm      |      |
langnoremap    | lnr     |  X   | nolangnoremap    nolnr     invlangnoremap    invlnr
langremap      | lrm     |  X   | nolangremap      nolrm     invlangremap      invlrm
laststatus     | ls      |      |
lazyredraw     | lz      |  X   | nolazyredraw     nolz      invlazyredraw     invlz
linebreak      | lbr     |  X   | nolinebreak      nolbr     invlinebreak      invlbr
lines          |         |      |
linespace      | lsp     |      |
lisp           |         |  X   | nolisp                     invlisp
lispwords      | lw      |      |
list           |         |  X   | nolist                     invlist
listchars      | lcs     |      |
loadplugins    | lpl     |  X   | noloadplugins    nolpl     invloadplugins    invlpl
luadll         |         |      |
macatsui       |         |  X   | nomacatsui                 invmacatsui
magic          |         |  X   | nomagic                    invmagic
makeef         | mef     |      |
makeprg        | mp      |      |
matchpairs     | mps     |      |
matchtime      | mat     |      |
maxcombine     | mco     |      |
maxfuncdepth   | mfd     |      |
maxmapdepth    | mmd     |      |
maxmem         | mm      |      |
maxmempattern  | mmp     |      |
maxmemtot      | mmt     |      |
menuitems      | mis     |      |
mkspellmem     | msm     |      |
modeline       | ml      |  X   | nomodeline       noml      invmodeline       invml
modelines      | mls     |      |
modifiable     | ma      |  X   | nomodifiable     noma      invmodifiable     invma
modified       | mod     |  X   | nomodified       nomod     invmodified       invmod
more           |         |  X   | nomore                     invmore
mouse          |         |      |
mousefocus     | mousef  |  X   | nomousefocus     nomousef  invmousefocus     invmousef
mousehide      | mh      |  X   | nomousehide      nomh      invmousehide      invmh
mousemodel     | mousem  |      |
mouseshape     | mouses  |      |
mousetime      | mouset  |      |
mzquantum      | mzq     |      |
nrformats      | nf      |      |
number         | nu      |  X   | nonumber         nonu      invnumber         invnu
numberwidth    | nuw     |      |
omnifunc       | ofu     |      |
opendevice     | odev    |  X   | noopendevice     noodev    invopendevice     invodev
operatorfunc   | opfunc  |      |
osfiletype     | oft     |      |
packpath       | pp      |      |
paragraphs     | para    |      |
paste          |         |  X   | nopaste                    invpaste
pastetoggle    | pt      |      |
patchexpr      | pex     |      |
patchmode      | pm      |      |
path           | pa      |      |
perldll        |         |      |
preserveindent | pi      |  X   | nopreserveindent nopi      invpreserveindent invpi
previewheight  | pvh     |      |
previewwindow  |         |  X   | nopreviewwindow            invpreviewwindow
printdevice    | pdev    |      |
printencoding  | penc    |      |
printexpr      | pexpr   |      |
printfont      | pfn     |      |
printheader    | pheader |      |
printmbcharset | pmbcs   |      |
printmbfont    | pmbfn   |      |
printoptions   | popt    |      |
prompt         |         |  X   | noprompt                   invprompt
pumheight      | ph      |      |
pvw            |         |  X   | nopvw                      invpvw
pythondll      |         |      |
pythonthreedll |         |      |
quoteescape    | qe      |      |
readonly       | ro      |  X   | noreadonly       noro      invreadonly       invro
redrawtime     | rdt     |      |
regexpengine   | re      |      |
relativenumber | rnu     |  X   | norelativenumber nornu     invrelativenumber invrnu
remap          |         |  X   | noremap                    invremap
renderoptions  | rop     |      |
report         |         |      |
restorescreen  | rs      |  X   | norestorescreen  nors      invrestorescreen  invrs
revins         | ri      |  X   | norevins         nori      invrevins         invri
rightleft      | rl      |  X   | norightleft      norl      invrightleft      invrl
rightleftcmd   | rlc     |      |
rubydll        |         |      |
ruler          | ru      |  X   | noruler          noru      invruler          invru
rulerformat    | ruf     |      |
runtimepath    | rtp     |      |
scroll         | scr     |      |
scrollbind     | scb     |  X   | noscrollbind     noscb     invscrollbind     invscb
scrolljump     | sj      |      |
scrolloff      | so      |      |
scrollopt      | sbo     |      |
sections       | sect    |      |
secure         |         |  X   | nosecure                   invsecure
selection      | sel     |      |
selectmode     | slm     |      |
sessionoptions | ssop    |      |
shell          | sh      |      |
shellcmdflag   | shcf    |      |
shellpipe      | sp      |      |
shellquote     | shq     |      |
shellredir     | srr     |      |
shellslash     | ssl     |  X   | noshellslash     nossl     invshellslash     invssl
shelltemp      | stmp    |  X   | noshelltemp      nostmp    invshelltemp      invstmp
shelltype      | st      |      |
shellxescape   | sxe     |      |
shellxquote    | sxq     |      |
shiftround     | sr      |  X   | noshiftround     nosr      invshiftround     invsr
shiftwidth     | sw      |      |
shortmess      | shm     |      |
shortname      | sn      |  X   | noshortname      nosn      invshortname      invsn
showbreak      | sbr     |      |
showcmd        | sc      |  X   | noshowcmd        nosc      invshowcmd        invsc
showfulltag    | sft     |  X   | noshowfulltag    nosft     invshowfulltag    invsft
showmatch      | sm      |  X   | noshowmatch      nosm      invshowmatch      invsm
showmode       | smd     |  X   | noshowmode       nosmd     invshowmode       invsmd
showtabline    | stal    |      |
sidescroll     | ss      |      |
sidescrolloff  | siso    |      |
signcolumn     | scl     |      |
smartcase      | scs     |  X   | nosmartcase      noscs     invsmartcase      invscs
smartindent    | si      |  X   | nosmartindent    nosi      invsmartindent    invsi
smarttab       | sta     |  X   | nosmarttab       nosta     invsmarttab       invsta
softtabstop    | sts     |      |
spell          |         |  X   | nospell                    invspell
spellcapcheck  | spc     |      |
spellfile      | spf     |      |
spelllang      | spl     |      |
spellsuggest   | sps     |      |
splitbelow     | sb      |  X   | nosplitbelow     nosb      invsplitbelow     invsb
splitright     | spr     |  X   | nosplitright     nospr     invsplitright     invspr
startofline    | sol     |  X   | nostartofline    nosol     invstartofline    invsol
statusline     | stl     |      |
suffixes       | su      |      |
suffixesadd    | sua     |      |
swapfile       | swf     |  X   | noswapfile       noswf     invswapfile       invswf
swapsync       | sws     |      |
switchbuf      | swb     |      |
synmaxcol      | smc     |      |
syntax         | syn     |      |
tabline        | tal     |      |
tabpagemax     | tpm     |      |
tabstop        | ts      |      |
tagbsearch     | tbs     |  X   | notagbsearch     notbs     invtagbsearch     invtbs
tagcase        | tc      |      |
taglength      | tl      |      |
tagrelative    | tr      |  X   | notagrelative    notr      invtagrelative    invtr
tags           | tag     |      |
tagstack       | tgst    |  X   | notagstack       notgst    invtagstack       invtgst
tcldll         |         |      |
term           |         |      |
termbidi       | tbidi   |  X   | notermbidi       notbidi   invtermbidi       invtbidi
termencoding   | tenc    |      |
termguicolors  | tgc     |      |
terse          |         |  X   | noterse                    invterse
textauto       | ta      |  X   | notextauto       nota      invtextauto       invta
textmode       | tx      |  X   | notextmode       notx      invtextmode       invtx
textwidth      | tw      |      |
thesaurus      | tsr     |      |
tildeop        | top     |  X   | notildeop        notop     invtildeop        invtop
timeout        | to      |  X   | notimeout        noto      invtimeout        invto
timeoutlen     | tm      |      |
title          |         |  X   | notitle                    invtitle
titlelen       |         |      |
titleold       |         |      |
titlestring    |         |      |
toolbar        | tb      |      |
toolbariconsize| tbis    |      |
ttimeout       |         |  X   | nottimeout                 invttimeout
ttimeoutlen    | ttm     |      |
ttybuiltin     | tbi     |  X   | nottybuiltin     notbi     invttybuiltin     invtbi
ttyfast        | tf      |  X   | nottyfast        notf      invttyfast        invtf
ttymouse       | ttym    |      |
ttyscroll      | tsl     |      |
ttytype        | tty     |      |
undodir        | udir    |      |
undofile       | udf     |  X   | noundofile       noudf     invundofile       invudf
undolevels     | ul      |      |
undoreload     | ur      |      |
updatecount    | uc      |      |
updatetime     | ut      |      |
verbose        | vbs     |      |
verbosefile    | vfile   |      |
viewdir        | vdir    |      |
viewoptions    | vop     |      |
viminfo        | vi      |      |
virtualedit    | ve      |      |
visualbell     | vb      |  X   | novisualbell     novb      invvisualbell     invvb
warn           |         |  X   | nowarn                     invwarn
weirdinvert    | wiv     |  X   | noweirdinvert    nowiv     invweirdinvert    invwiv
whichwrap      | ww      |      |
wildchar       | wc      |      |
wildcharm      | wcm     |      |
wildignore     | wig     |      |
wildignorecase | wic     |  X   | nowildignorecase nowic     invwildignorecase invwic
wildmenu       | wmnu    |  X   | nowildmenu       nowmnu    invwildmenu       invwmnu
wildmode       | wim     |      |
wildoptions    | wop     |      |
winaltkeys     | wak     |      |
window         | wi      |      |
winfixheight   | wfh     |  X   | nowinfixheight   nowfh     invwinfixheight   invwfh
winfixwidth    | wfw     |  X   | nowinfixwidth    nowfw     invwinfixwidth    invwfw
winheight      | wh      |      |
winminheight   | wmh     |      |
winminwidth    | wmw     |      |
winwidth       | wiw     |      |
wrap           |         |  X   | nowrap                     invwrap
wrapmargin     | wm      |      |
wrapscan       | ws      |  X   | nowrapscan       nows      invwrapscan       invws
write          |         |  X   | nowrite                    invwrite
writeany       | wa      |  X   | nowriteany       nowa      invwriteany       invwa
writebackup    | wb      |  X   | nowritebackup    nowb      invwritebackup    invwb
writedelay     | wd      |      |
```

Comment: Could you add a version (+ patchlevel) to this post so future searchers will know what version this table references?

Comment: Nice one Benoit ... very useful table, at least as a reference when one cannot recall a particular option.

Answer (score 2):

In the help it shows you the minimum amount required. But in general, you only need enough to be unique. So `:set numb` is fine too.

See in the help how the `[mber]` is in square brackets? That means it's not necessary.

```
:[range]nu[mber] [count] [flags]
            Same as :print, but precede each line with its line
            number.  (See also 'highlight' and 'numberwidth'
            option).
            See |ex-flags| for [flags].
```

Note: vim thinks of 'abbreviations' as something different - see `:help abbreviations` which describes how you can save time entering words.

Comment: -1, vim options, contrarily to commands, have only two forms (plus the prefixed `inv-` and `no-`). `:set numb` won't work. You provided the help for a vim **command**, OP asks about **options**. The right help section is `:help 'nu'`, not `:help :nu`.

Comment: sorry Peter, seems Benoit's answer is more suitable = =

Comment: @CHENZhao: not only more suitable, but more correct! Thanks Benoit, I appreciate the clarification and I didn't realize/think through this subtlety.